# Organizing Data for a Neural Network in Caffe

Tags: dataset, hdf5, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am trying to prepare data for use in a neural network. And I am rather lost in all of the documentation. Many Caffe examples provide pre-prepared data but I am looking to prepare my own. My goal is to have my neural network use input images (let's call them *x*) and output different images (lets call these *y*). I've decided to use HDF5 files to store my data using python (which I know how to do). However, I want to "show" the neural net *x* and *y* and have it output *y-hat*, as in an image similar to the desired output, *y*.

But, I'm not sure how exactly most convolutional neural nets encapsulate the inputs and desired outputs to feed into the neural net (ie, how classification nets are fed the labels with the data). Am I supposed to put *x* and *y* into the same HDF5 dataset then later into a Caffe data layer? If so am I to organize the dataset like: (*x1, y1, x2, y2, ...*) or like (*x1, x2, ..., xn, y1, y2, ..., yn*).
Or should the ideal output, *y*, and the inputs, *x*, be sorted into a separate datasets? And if so can I load both of them into the Caffe data layer?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What examples have you found that are closest to what you're trying to do?  I work in basic image classification, but I might be able to translate to your paradigm.

Comment: @Prune I suppose the closest I can think of is a kind of combination between image classification convolutional neural nets like Caffe's MNIST example and pixel-wise classification that is often used for image segmentation something like this: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4038v2.pdf example of semantic segmentation. I hope that's a little clearer. In the end I want to read in images and output "annotated" images.

Comment: If I understand your explanation correctly, your problem is that you're trying to apply a classification solution (pigeon-hole each input as one of a finite, given set of choices) to a transformation type of problem.  You want to input a lot of (x, y) pairs to train the model.  Once the model is trained, you want to input an image **z**, and get a transformed image **z-hat**, which is not found in the set of **y** images in training.  Is this correct?  Rather, you want a change to **z** that's in the same vein as the training x->y changes.

Comment: @Prune Yes, I think you've understood my intentions. My team and I are rather confused and aren't sure if this approach is an appropriate one. Since Caffe's examples use preprocessed/organized data we aren't sure how they organized their training data before feeding it to the net.

Answer (score 0):

I've batted this around my head for a while, volleyed it off a couple of friends, and the best I've come up with so far is to focus the paradigm.

This is actually a complex prediction task, not a classification task.  What you have is a sort of multivariate transformation.  I believe that you'll want to organize the data set as (x1, y1), (x2, y2), with your output prediction being a vector (the image in linear format) or matrix, corresponding to the penultimate layer of the NN.

Comment: Thanks for responding, @Prune! My team and I will try this method and update this post as soon as our hardware becomes available (there is currently some testing happening that's paused progress).

Comment: Great; I hope it helped.  The problem is to train the model in a not-too-string fashion, so that you teach it transformations (processes), rather than strict classifications.